# problema con fecha 0000-00-00 00:00:00 en procedimientos almacenados en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con un procedimiento almacenado en mysql que está mas o menos de esta forma

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`user_no_root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `sp_1`(
    in _id int          
    )
begin
    declare _empresa_id int;
    if(fn_validar_token(_usuario_id,_token,_origen,_success_code,_error_token_code)=_error_token_code) then
        select _error_token_code;
    else 
         select is, 
            case when su.fecha_ingreso!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' then date_format(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') else ' 'end as ingreso
        from table
        where id = _id;
         
    end if;
 end ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

pero al realizar un call me lanza el sig: error:
Error Code: 1525 Incorrect DATE value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
el problema es que al ejecutar el select sin el procedimiento almacenado funciona correctamente, ya intente cambiando el mysql-mode pero el problema persiste .

agradecería mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Debe verificar el [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) específico del procedimiento almacenado (stored procedure) asignado cuando se creó dicho procedimiento almacenado que puede ser distinto del activo de la sesión y/o global. Para obtener el [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) específico del procedimiento almacenado puede usar una sentencia como la siguiente en su caso:

```sql
SELECT
  `ROUTINE_NAME`,
  `SQL_MODE`
FROM
  `information_schema`.`ROUTINES`
WHERE
  `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND
  `ROUTINE_TYPE` = 'PROCEDURE' AND
  `ROUTINE_NAME` = 'sp_1';
```

Puede cambiar el [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) de la sesión con una sentencia como la siguiente:

```sql
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode := '';
```

sin embargo, eso no cambiaría el [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) del procedimiento almacenado.

Puede ver un ejemplo completo en el siguiente [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=676af81690b7b3c6ae1630870cb01f53).

Comment: Muchas gracias, estuve varios días leyendo por todo internet y no encontraba la solución. tu solución funciona perfectamente